# How to tell when a user taps in a UITableViewCell?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I'm working on an iOS app where I have UIWebviews inside UITableViewCells. The UIWebViews take up about 50% of the cell and the rest of the cell is blank. I need to be able to respond when a user taps in one of my cells. I've tried implementing the `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method, but this only responds when a user taps in a part of my cell that does NOT contain a uiwebview.  Is there any way in which I can respond to a tap regardless of where in my cell the user taped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set `userInteractionEnabled` property of your `UIWebView` to `NO`, but in this case you will not be able to scroll it..

Answer (score 1):

Your design is definitely bad: Apple explicitly says in the UIWebView class reference, that you **should not add UIWebViews to table cells**. Also, as the web view internally manages an UIScrollView, which captures all the touches. So the only way to do what you want is to subclass UIWebView and override the touch management methods. This is also not advisable, as **UIWebView is one of the few classes which are not to be subclassed according to Apple.**

You have to seriously reconsider your design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

First, do [this](http://mithin.in/2009/08/26/detecting-taps-and-events-on-uiwebview-the-right-way) to your webview. Then, call the tableView's `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method when a tap is registered. Kind of a pain, but the only way I can think of. This will allow the user to interact with the webview in a completely normal way, but sends lets the table know which cell is being interacted with. If that's not what you want, the other answers should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try attaching a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to your cell.